# trig identity proof help working LHS only

Tags: trigonometry

$$(cos\theta - sec \theta)^2=\tan^{2}\left(\theta\right)-\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)$$

I worked on LHS but not sure if I should put all of LHS in terms of sine/cos.

Comment: If you do put everything in terms of $sin$ and $cos$, then just about the only identity you have to worry about is $\sin^{2}\theta+\cos^{2}\theta=1$. So that's not a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\left(\cos\theta -\frac{1}{\cos\theta}\right)^2 = 
\left(\frac{\cos^2\theta - 1}{\cos\theta}\right)^2 
=\left(\frac{-\sin^2\theta }{\cos\theta}\right)^2 \\
=\left(\frac{\sin^4\theta }{\cos^2\theta}\right)  
=\left(\frac{\sin^2\theta \left[1-\cos^2\theta\right]}{\cos^2\theta}\right)  
=\tan^2\theta -\sin^2\theta
$$

Comment: thanks, that makes it very clear. i appreciate your time

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$(\cos\theta-\sec\theta)^2=\cos^2\theta-2+\sec^2\theta=(\sec^2\theta-1)-(1-\cos^2\theta)=\tan^2\theta-\sin^2\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ -1 = \tan^2\theta -\sec^2\theta = \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta -2
$$
so
$$ \tan^2\theta - \sin^2\theta = \cos^2\theta -2 + \sec^2\theta \\
= \cos^2\theta -2\cos\theta\sec\theta + \sec^2\theta \\
=(\cos\theta-\sec\theta)^2 
$$